# I am not able to do simple database update using codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am using a very simple code to update database using php codeigniter. But I am unable to update

Here is my view code that calls controller:

```
<input type="button" value="Approve" name="approve" id="approve" onclick="<?php echo base_url(); ?>inc/setStatusApprove/<?php echo $members['user_id']; ?>/<?php echo $members['user_company_id']; ?>">
```

This is my conroller function :

```
public function setStatusApprove($userid,$company_id){
$this->me->setStatusApprove($userid,$company_id);
}
```

And here is my model function :

```
function setStatusApprove($userid,$company_id){
    $query="update user_profiles set user_profile_is_active = 1 where user_id=" .$userid . "  and user_company_id =" . $company_id . " ";
    $query = $this->db->query($query);
}
```

But it is not updating the database. Please help.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $query;`?

Comment: first thing is remove `. " "` portion from your query that is not required neither all other concatenation as double quote can parse variable in php.

Comment: prafulla kumar sahu, thanks for the info. But it doesn't make any change.

Comment: set this to from and write this in action submit

Comment: Your statement make sence!!@Abdulla

Comment: ankiiG .where can I echo $query?. I am new to codeigniter.

Comment: @Abdulla you should echo your query just after you are setting it. After `$query="update user_profiles set user_profile_is_active = 1 where user_id=" .$userid . "  and user_company_id =" . $company_id . " ";` line .and use `exit;` after echo .

Comment: @Abdulla why you should not use unnecessary quote is, that will minimize the chance of  typo error.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu its tagging me too

Comment: how could I know which one I should tag :(

Comment: Solved it. Thanks Abdulla. I have changed my view file-changed input type button to form input type =submit. Now its updating the database. its going to a blank page How can I stay in the same page?

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. God bless you

Answer (score 2):

Just write your query using `Active record`.Active records is safe, it will save you from SQL injections

```
$this->db->set('user_profile_is_active', 1);
$this->db->where('user_id', $userid);
$this->db->where('user_company_id', $company_id);
$this->db->update('user_profiles');
```

Instead of using `onclick function` you need to write you url in your `form action` as

```
action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>inc/setStatusApprove/<?php echo $members['user_id']; ?>/<?php echo $members['user_company_id']; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function setStatusApprove($userid,$company_id){
              //echo $userid." ".$company_id;
              // die;

               $data = array(
               'user_profile_is_active' => 1,
              );

             $this->db->where(array("user_id"=>$userid, "user_company_id"=>$company_id ));
             $this->db->update('user_profiles', $data); 

            redirect("your home controller name");

}
```

replace above code in ur model function.. first check your model function geting proper parmeter values.. if function  geting proper values.. then above code will work fine as you want. try it..

Answer (score 0):

Simply do it using codeigniter active records. Also make sure you are getting parameters in the function and try to print query at the end of the function using `$this->db->last_query()` if this does not works.

```
function setStatusApprove($userid,$company_id){

$this->db->where('user_id', $userid);
$this->db->where('company_id', $company_id);    
return $this->db->update('user_profiles', array('user_profile_is_active' , 1); 
}
```